# client vs server. is one doing ajax calls for example ever time i need run some sort of calculation?

Tags: javascript, node.js

for example:

If i am using an npm package, i can only use it on server side js. Does that mean one will always have to send data through ajax post/get request for example to server side do the calculation then send data back? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

I am aware of how react works etc and i am aware of workarounds to get require to work browser side, but for sake of understanding workflow and how it should all be set up I ask this question.

I am currently using express with nodejs and using ajax calls to talk to server side js and send info back. So want to know if there is a better way of doing this?

Comment: What do you mean that you can only use npm packages on the server side? While there are some packages that require a node.js environment, not all of them do.

Comment: yes you are correct. Just wondering about when using npm packages server side, is ajax or other post/get methods the best way to communicate with the server?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no "better" way to send data from the client browser to the server than an ajax call. Alternativelly you can use a normal form, or url parameters to pass the server some variable with the page load request.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the npm package you are using to do your calculations, you can just serve that .js library up along with your .html page by moving that script into a static assets folder and referencing it with a `<script>` tag. Then, you can do the calculation entirely in the browser (client-side) assuming you don't need any other I/O (db, etc.).